# Vertical alignment and positioning of rotated text in a table or grid

Tags: html, css, html-table, rotation, css-grid

I'm trying to rotate some text in an html table, but no matter what I do I end up with some alignment and text-flow issues.

I've tried using various combinations of writing-mode and rotate in css, but cannot sort out the issue. Here's the test table: https://universaltheosophy.com/hpb/test-table.htm

Here's the code:

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.c10 {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.text-body-2-western {
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

.c90bt {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="text-body-2-western c90bt"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western">MAIN TITLE OF THE TABLE SHOULD CENTER HORIZONTALLY</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="text-body-2-western c90bt"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits but for some reason reaches outside of it.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western"><img src="https://universaltheosophy.com/resources/sd-2-300-blank.png"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western text-body-no-spacing"><span class="c10">bottom title in small caps.</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is primarily in two places:

1. the rotated text doesn't properly align within the top and bottom boundary of the table td element. Either the text extends outside of the td boundary or it gets squished together (when you run the code snippet here, see the difference between the normal view and the full page view)
2. the text aligns horizontally far away from the image at the center (I want the rotated text on either side of the image in the center to be tight against it).

**Edit**

To address the first comment here (re: the rowspans), here's the same table without rowspans, with the same result:

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.c10 {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.text-body-2-western {
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

.c90bt {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p class="text-body-2-western">MAIN TITLE OF THE TABLE SHOULD CENTER HORIZONTALLY.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western c90bt"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western"><img src="https://universaltheosophy.com/resources/sd-2-300-blank.png" class="img1"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-body-2-western c90bt"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits but for some reason reaches outside of it.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p class="text-body-2-western text-body-no-spacing"><span class="c10">bottom title in small caps.</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why do you have the `row-span`s?

Comment: in order to make the two paragraphs (on the left and right side) the full height of the table, so the rowspan creates a single cell that does just that. But it's inconsequential to the issue at hand, as a table without rowspans has the same issues.

Edit: I added the same table without rowspans so you can see the snippet there, and the same issues resulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a *different* solution to your problem using [`CSS grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

1. Note the change in markup without using tables. Create a *grid layout* using `display: grid` - note that the `&nbsp` in the markup is for an *empty* grid item.
2. Make a three-column layout with `min-content` width using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content)` on the outer container.
3. Fit the second row to the height of the middle element by using `grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content`
4. For the vertical alignment, I am using `writing-mode`:

   ```
   .wmode {
      writing-mode: tb-rl;
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
   }
   ```

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
  justify-content: center;
}

.c10 {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.text-body-2-western {
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

.wmode {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  &nbsp;
  <p class="text-body-2-western">MAIN TITLE OF THE TABLE SHOULD CENTER HORIZONTALLY</p>
  &nbsp;
  <p class="text-body-2-western wmode"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits.</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x338?text=image">
  <p class="text-body-2-western wmode"><span class="c10">test title.</span><br>this is a test string of text rotated vertically that should fit within the table td limits but for some reason reaches outside of it.</p>
  &nbsp;
  <p class="text-body-2-western text-body-no-spacing"><span class="c10">bottom title in small caps.</span></p>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an ideal solution. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, one remaining issue, which is something I hadn't included in my post. I'll want the image to scale down for mobile devices, so I have an img class for that, like so:

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) { .img1 { width: 100% } }`

If you add that, then the rotated text on the left side overlaps on top of the image. So I need to find some way to keep that text from overlapping...

Comment: You can create a *wrapper* for the image and set a width for the *wrapper* and width 100% for the image in mobile view... Another thing to note is that `writing-mode`, `min-content` and `CSS grid layouts` are newer CSS3 specs...